# How does "show desktop" work?

Tags: gnome, system, wmctrl

How does <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> work to show the desktop?
Does it minimize all windows?
Or does it set the desktop as "on top"?
Or does it make all windows invisible?

Can I exclude certain windows/applications from "show desktop"?

Answer (score 0):

Where do you see a "show desktop" option?

There is no invisible windows unless an application creates such. It will minimize the windows. It may be possible to avoid that action if your window does not allow for *minimization*.

Also the desktop cannot be "on top" because it is the parent window of all the windows created by applications. In other words, those windows are inside the desktop window anyway. Actually, some X11 desktop implementations show large icons in the desktop window when a (child) window is minimized.

Comment: With "Show desktop" I mean SUPER+D or the icon in the launcher.
Hm do you know how to check if the desktop is shown? I want an application to stay visible (e.g. conky or a notes-app) and thus listen to the show-desktop-state.

Comment: If you want to avoid the problem on an existing application, I'm afraid you'd have to recompile it first... Not too sure you'd want to do that? As for how it is programmed, I'm not 100% sure, but I would imagine that it simply lists all the top windows and sends a "minimize window" message to each one of those top windows.